# Modify a Powershell script to execute against multiple different computer target

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to modify the below script, so it can be executed against all DFS server member or multiple servers, rather than manually RDP-ing into each server and then execute this script.

The existing script works when `$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName` but not when the target server is multiple.

Script Purpose below: Check and report the backlog of DFS File server replication. It would be great if the exported result is also as.CSV file so it can be sorted based on the server name.

```
Param (
    [String[]]$ReplicationGroupList = ("")
)

$RGroups = Get-WmiObject  -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDFS" -Query "SELECT * FROM DfsrReplicationGroupConfig"
#If replication groups specified, use only those.
if ($ReplicationGroupList) {
    $SelectedRGroups = @()
    foreach ($ReplicationGroup IN $ReplicationGroupList) {
        $SelectedRGroups += $rgroups | Where-Object { $_.ReplicationGroupName -eq $ReplicationGroup }
    }
    if ($SelectedRGroups.count -eq 0) {
        Write-Error "None of the group names specified were found, exiting"
        exit
    }
    else {
        $RGroups = $SelectedRGroups
    }
}

$ComputerName = Get-DfsrMember | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ComputerName -Unique | Sort-Object
$Succ = 0
$Warn = 0
$Err = 0
Start-Transcript -path "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\dfsr1.txt"
foreach ($Group in $RGroups) {
    $RGFoldersWMIQ = "SELECT * FROM DfsrReplicatedFolderConfig WHERE ReplicationGroupGUID='" + $Group.ReplicationGroupGUID + "'"
    $RGFolders = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDFS" -Query  $RGFoldersWMIQ
    $RGConnectionsWMIQ = "SELECT * FROM DfsrConnectionConfig WHERE ReplicationGroupGUID='" + $Group.ReplicationGroupGUID + "'"
    $RGConnections = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDFS" -Query  $RGConnectionsWMIQ
    foreach ($Connection in $RGConnections) {
        $ConnectionName = $Connection.PartnerName#.Trim()
        if ($Connection.Enabled -eq $True) {
            if (((New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.ping).send("$ConnectionName")).Status -eq "Success") {
                foreach ($Folder in $RGFolders) {
                    $RGName = $Group.ReplicationGroupName
                    $RFName = $Folder.ReplicatedFolderName

                    if ($Connection.Inbound -eq $True) {
                        $SendingMember = $ConnectionName
                        $ReceivingMember = $ComputerName
                        $Direction = "inbound"
                    }
                    else {
                        $SendingMember = $ComputerName
                        $ReceivingMember = $ConnectionName
                        $Direction = "outbound"
                    }

                    $BLCommand = "dfsrdiag Backlog /RGName:'" + $RGName + "' /RFName:'" + $RFName + "' /SendingMember:" + $SendingMember + " /ReceivingMember:" + $ReceivingMember
                    $Backlog = Invoke-Expression -Command $BLCommand

                    $BackLogFilecount = 0
                    foreach ($item in $Backlog) {
                        if ($item -ilike "*Backlog File count*") {
                            $BacklogFileCount = [int]$Item.Split(":")[1].Trim()
                        }
                    }

                    if ($BacklogFileCount -eq 0) {
                        $Color = "white"
                        $Succ = $Succ + 1
                    }
                    elseif ($BacklogFilecount -lt 10) {
                        $Color = "yellow"
                        $Warn = $Warn + 1
                    }
                    else {
                        $Color = "red"
                        $Err = $Err + 1
                    }
                    Write-Output "$BacklogFileCount files in backlog $SendingMember->$ReceivingMember for $RGName"

                } # Closing iterate through all folders
            } # Closing  If replies to ping
        } # Closing  If Connection enabled
    } # Closing iteration through all connections
} # Closing iteration through all groups
Write-Output "$Succ successful, $Warn warnings and $Err errors from $($Succ+$Warn+$Err) replications."
Stop-Transcript

$file = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\dfsr1.txt"

get-content $file |
Select-Object -Skip 18 |
set-content "$file-temp"
Move-Item "$file-temp" $file -Force

$emailrecipients = "boss@it.com";
$emailbody = Get-Content -Path "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\dfsr1.txt" -Raw

Send-MailMessage -to $emailrecipients -smtpserver smtp.domain.COM -from "$env:COMPUTERNAME@$env:userdnsdomain" -subject "DFSR Report for $(get-date -format dd/MM/yyyy) from $env:COMPUTERNAME" -body $emailbody;

Remove-Item "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\dfsr1.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming WinRM is already configured in the environment, you don't need to modify the script - just execute it as-is on the remote targets with `Invoke-Command`:

```
$RemoteDFSServers = "dfs01","dfs2","dfs3"

Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\path\to\existing\script.ps1 -ComputerName $RemoteDFSServers
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, does that C: drive can be changed into UNC PATH on a network drive?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer `-FilePath` is a local path, so as long as it's accessible from the source session, yes

Comment: that's great, thank you Mat.